# Mac like screenshot in Windows with shadow

Tags: windows, osx, images, screenshot

I want to take screenshots in windows just like mac does with shadowing. As you can see in the Mac version there is a cool shadow behind it. How can I achieve to do this in windows?

Mac: 
[image: mac]

Windows:
[image: windows]

Comment: Are you willing to pay?

Comment: Depends but for short answer no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free and open source [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) allows you to add Drop Shadows to screenshots:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html), but you need to pay. It's worth the money you pay for and not only achieves shadows, but also transparency in Aero style apps (not just background, the Window Border as well!)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses free software ([GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is open source and runs on Win/Lin/Mac)

Download and install [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or if you're on a Chromebook use [Sumopaint](http://www.sumopaint.com/home/)

All you need to do is open the image and add a `drop shadow` (That's what "that" effect is called)

Then save your image.
It's that simple!